# copy/duplicate live data from div to textarea using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I have create a rich text editor using DIV as editor container. How can I pass the DIV value to textarea? I already use jquery code. it success when I view it live but when I submit the form, the textarea value is empty. Here is my code:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="rte" contenteditable="true" unselectable="off">
</div>
<textarea name='rteHide' id='stage'></textarea>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
$("#rte").keyup(function() {
    var content = $('#rte').html();
    $("#stage").text(content);
});
});
```

I'm using this for wordpress plugin. Please let me know if there any other way to pass DIV value without using .post() jquery. Or using textarea as rich text editor container.

I required to create this editor instead using the current existing rich editor because we want to do enhancement in future.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `val()` instead of `text()` to set the value of your `textarea`

```
$("#stage").val(content);
```

Also, to make sure that there's no conflict happen here, you can wrap your code inside:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#rte").keyup(function() {
        var content = $('#rte').html();
        $("#stage").val(content);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. but still cannot post the value...even i'm using .val(), .text() and .html(). I can view the inserted data when i'm typing but when i clicked submit, the textarea is empty.

Comment: Can you post the code where you retrieve the textarea value?

Comment: I;m using wordpress. Here is code to save the textarea data:  function page_style_postdata( $post_id ) 
{               
        $page_style_post=htmlspecialchars($_POST['rteHide']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'testnewmeta', $page_style_post );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'page_style_postdata' );